# dreamweaver templates keep putting absolute addresses in script src

Tags: dreamweaver, dreamweaver-templates

I moved a set of templates to a new folder also named Templates so the instructional designer can see them in her "New page from Template" window.  For some reason, I as the programmer can see the list if I try to make a new page from template, but the ID couldn't.  While moving them allowed her to see them, it broke all the relative links to the js script src files.  And when she tries to save the template page, it tells her to try and copy files and the absolute links don't get reset to their relative paths.

Is there a way to reset the relative links to those .dwt files?  When I open the .dwt files, the relative links look correct; but when the ID makes a new page and then chooses a template to use, the links break at that point.

What do I need to do make the templates retain the relative links again?

Thanks in advance!
Carlos

Answer (score 0):

When I moved the templates, it wasn't just in a new folder, but on a new level in the folder structure, so the old script src address "../../scripts/nav.js" wouldn't work because in its new location, it overshot the folder by one level and hence couldn't find the js file in question.  Readjusting the relative links to compensate for its new location and structure level fixed this issue.

Carlos